# Computer Selecting Different Answers in Rock Paper Scissors JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript following The Odin Project's curriculum and I have run into an issue making the Rock-Paper-Scissors project. When I play a round of the game I get a result, but when I look in the console at the actual value of the variable for my computer's selection, 'computerSelection', it doesn't always match up to what is displayed on the web page. I also assigned the function computerPlay() to computerSelection so the random choice of the computer could be used in the fullGame() function, but they also are usually different values. What is making them all different? I can't see where I have gone wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
let userSelection = '';
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let scoreboard = document.querySelector('.scoreboard')
let playerScore = document.querySelector('.playerScore')
let cpuScore = document.querySelector('.cpuScore')
let tiedScore = document.querySelector('.tiedScore')
let reset = document.querySelector('.resetBtn')

//Rock, Paper, Scissor Choices 
const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

//Rounds of the game
let rounds = 1;
//Starting scoreboard
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let tiedMatches = 0;

//Computer picks Rock/Paper/Scissors 
let computerSelection = computerPlay();

function computerPlay() {
  return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * [choices.length])];
}

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.choice')
btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Player picks Rock/Paper/Scissors
    userSelection = btn.textContent;
    //Plays the game with button click
    fullGame(computerSelection, userSelection);
    playFullGame();
  })
})

//Function for full 7 round game
function fullGame(computerSelection, userSelection) {
  computerSelection = computerPlay();
  if (computerSelection === userSelection) {
    let tieGame = document.createElement('div');
    tieGame.textContent = 'It\'s a tie!';
    result.appendChild(tieGame);
    result.textContent = tieGame.textContent;
    ++tiedMatches
    tiedScore.textContent = tiedMatches;
  } else if ((computerSelection === 'Rock' && userSelection === 'Scissors') || (computerSelection === 'Scissors' && userSelection === 'Paper') || (computerSelection === 'Paper' && userSelection === 'Rock' && (computerScore <= 5 || userScore <= 5))) {
    let loseGame = document.createElement('div');
    loseGame.textContent = `You lose. ${computerSelection} beats ${userSelection}.`;
    result.appendChild(loseGame);
    result.textContent = loseGame.textContent;
    ++computerScore
    cpuScore.textContent = computerScore;
    ++rounds;
  } else if ((computerSelection === 'Scissors' && userSelection === 'Rock') || (computerSelection === 'Paper' && userSelection === 'Scissors') || (computerSelection === 'Rock' && userSelection === 'Paper' && (computerScore <= 5 || userScore <= 5))) {
    let winGame = document.createElement('div');
    winGame.textContent = `You win! ${userSelection} beats ${computerSelection}.`;
    result.appendChild(winGame);
    result.textContent = winGame.textContent;
    ++userScore
    playerScore.textContent = userScore;
    ++rounds;
  }
}

function playFullGame() {
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    fullGame();
  }
  if (userScore == 4 || computerScore == 4 || tiedMatches == 4) {
    return endGameMessage();
  }
}

playFullGame();
//Victory or Defeat Message
let endGameMessage = function() {
  if (userScore > computerScore && userScore > tiedMatches && userScore === 4) {
    let winMessage = document.createElement('div');
    winMessage.classList.add('winMessage')
    winMessage.textContent = 'Congratulations! You have won the match!';
    result.appendChild(winMessage);
  } else if (computerScore > userScore && computerScore > tiedMatches && computerScore === 4) {
    let loseMessage = document.createElement('div');
    loseMessage.classList.add('loseMessage')
    loseMessage.textContent = 'The computer has won the match. Better luck next time.';
    result.appendChild(loseMessage);
  } else if ((computerScore === userScore && computerScore != 0 && userScore != 0) || tiedMatches > userScore || tiedMatches > computerScore) {
    let tieMessage = document.createElement('div');
    tieMessage.classList.add('tieMessage')
    tieMessage.textContent = 'You have tied with the computer.';
    result.appendChild(tieMessage);
  }
}

function resetGame() {
  playerScore.textContent = userScore = 0;
  cpuScore.textContent = computerScore = 0;
  tiedScore.textContent = tiedMatches = 0;
  result.textContent = '';
}
let resetButton = reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  resetGame();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock-Paper-Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="title">Rock-Paper-Scissors Game</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="scoreboard">
      <div class="playerSection">
        <div class="playerTitle">Player</div>
        <div class="playerScore">0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="computerSection">
        <div class="computerTitle">Computer</div>
        <div class="cpuScore">0</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tiedSection">
        <div class="tiedTitle">Ties</div>
        <div class="tiedScore">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
    <div class="choiceBtns">
      <button class="choice">Rock</button>
      <button class="choice">Paper</button>
      <button class="choice">Scissors</button>
    </div>
    <div class="reset">
      <button class="resetBtn">Click Here to Play Again</button>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You call the function with a computer selection: `fullGame(computerSelection, userSelection);` but inside the function you have the computer make another selection: `computerSelection = computerPlay();`. The function argument is the *previous* selection.

Comment: You don't need the function argument since the it gets a selection inside the function.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I really appreciate the help!